# Find angle of a point from center of circle

Tags: java, geometry

If I have an image 720, 720 that looks like this..

[image]

How do I work out the angle of the touched x,y given that the center x and y are 360, 360
A lot of calculations I see for this assume the origin is 0,0 (which is top left) so I get incorrect results.
I am assuming 0 is always to the top and not rotated.

Comment: What exactly did you find so far? If your problem is only about the coordinates of the center, we will be happy to help you!

Comment: Traditionally, 0 degrees is to the right, 90 is up, 180 is left, and 270 is down. (I may misunderstand your phrasing.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be clearer this way:

```
(Math.toDegrees( Math.atan2(fromLeft - 360.0, 360.0 - fromTop) ) + 360.0) % 360.0
```

Adding a 360 degree turn and applying the modulo operator gives you the positive angle, which atan2 does not.

Comment: This seems the closest to any solution suggested here.
I misunderstood in my previous comment, if I substitute x touch coordinate for fromLeft and y for fromTop I get a positive angle back at least.
Clicking at around 3 o'clock does give around 90 degrees as expected  
but if I click at 6 0'clock I get close to 360 degrees which wasn't expected, 9 o'clock reports the correct 270 degrees.
It looks like this is pretty close but still some problem with 12 and 6 o'clock in that calculation

Comment: If I click at 12 0'clock I get 180 and 6 o'clock I get 0 so these are somehow reversed.

Comment: Corrected from "fromTop - 360.0" to "360.0 - fromTop". Tested at JavaWIDE.

Comment: Did you test this snippet? `atan2` is defined (counterintuitively) as `atan2(y, x)` but you're passing `(x, y)`...

Comment: @Bill Thanks. I agree now that it's worthwhile to state clearly the coordinate axes that are used in this question. They are not oriented as usual for x-y coordinates in mathematics. They are oriented as usual for Java2D, Postscript, and so on. That is why I named my parameters `fromLeft` and `fromTop`. In regard to testing: Yes, I think you'll agree now that the point 720 from left, 360 from top, is at 90 degrees; the point 360 from left, 720 from top, is at 180 degrees.

Answer (score 19):

Here is the general formula:

```
angle = atan2(mouseY - cirleCenterY, mouseX - circleCenterX);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.Math.atan2(y-360,x-360);
```

Answer (score 0):

the screen coordinates don't go the way of the trigonometric ones.

use `java.lang.Math.atan2(-(y-360),x-360);`