# Finding angle from center point on circle

Tags: java, android, math, geometry, angle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find angle of a point from center of circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968500/find-angle-of-a-point-from-center-of-circle)

Imagine a circle, the center point is fixed, as is the point at the top of the circle. What i want is to give a third point anywhere around the circle (or outside the circle) and get the degrees from the center to top point line from 0-359. (I actually graphed out a nice picture illustrating but im new and cant post it)

To give some context, the circle is a little planet and I want do place a little building on the surface with the base of the building at a tangent. I need the rotation angle for my building bitmap.

edit: Thanks for the help, i'm still struggling with this one though. I wonder could it be relevant that I'm using android and the y0 coordinate is at the top? Is it the other way around on other platforms? would that affect the calculation?

Solution: Because I am in android and the y coords are counted from top to bottom I had to change a - witha +

```
degrees =  Math.atan2(x - centerX, -y + centerY);
// and to make it count 0-360
if (degrees < 0) {degrees += 2 * Math.PI;}
```

Comment: I'd look at sine and cosine in trigonometry.

Comment: That's what you need? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968500/find-angle-of-a-point-from-center-of-circle?rq=1

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964983/rotate-image-around-character-java/12971987#12971987) for a possible solution, or at least a push in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Math.atan2()` to get the angle in radians from east, and then rotate and convert as appropriate.

Note that `atan2` is defined as `atan2(y, x)` NOT `atan2(x, y)`, as you might expect.

Comment: This was pretty much it, my oversight was that I'm in Android and the Y coords are counted from top to bottom, in the end i just had to replace a - with +.

Answer (score 0):

Get the horizontal distance and the vertical difference between the center and the point, divide one by the other, and pass the result to the method [`Math.asin(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#asin%28double%29).

The result will be the angle in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). When you need it in degree, you can use the method [`Math.toDegrees(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees%28double%29). Most APIs I know prefer radians, though.